# How to put files from a sftp folder to a suitescript array? Also, is it possible to move or delete a file in sftp server using suite script 2.0?

Tags: sftp, suitescript2.0

I know how to copy a file in sftp server. But, how to put files in a sftp folder to a suitescript array?  Also, is it possible to move or delete a file in sftp server using suite script 2.0? If yes, how to do it?

The following coding is for copying a file in sftp:

```
    var myPwdGuid = "B34672495064525E5D65032D63B52301";
    var myHostKey = "AAA1234567890Q=";

    var connection = sftp.createConnection({
        username: 'myuser',
        passwordGuid: myPwdGuid,
        url: 'host.somewhere.com',
        directory: 'myuser/wheres/my/file',
        hostKey: myHostKey
    });

    var downloadedFile = connection.download({
        directory: 'relative/path/to/file',
        filename: 'downloadMe.js'
    });

    connection.upload({
        directory: 'relative/path/to/remote/dir',
        filename: 'copy_of_downloadme.js',
        file: downloadedFile,
        replaceExisting: true
    });
```

Comment: I just find out that sftp module doesn't include a way to list the files/folders on the SFTP server. I get this information from this site: http://www.upilioconsulting.com/2016/10/05/netsuite-2016-2-sftp-suitescript-2-0/. So, how do people download the file that they want from sftp server?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the SFTP module in its current version does not include a way to list the contents of a remote directory. In some scenarios the file name is known or predictable. For the other scenarios one can use a file with a known name to store the names of the other files or middleware to retrieve the list of files. Ask me if you want to know about an existing middleware solution.